# Exctract the model from PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an view with a model. In this view a form. I post this form to a action/controller with the code below. The action I call in the post return a partialview, this partialview is strongly-typed. The `data` variable below receive this partialview. The question is, is it possible to access the model used in the partialview ?

```
var jqxhr = $.post(....., {
    ....
},
function (data) {
    //(*)
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that code does nothing to illuminate your question.

Comment: I rephrased, I hope it's ok now :)

Comment: If you wrote what **exactly** you want to do, I'm sure you would get better answers.

Comment: It's not clear yet ? :) Where the (*), the content of data is a partialview strongly-typed, I'd like if possible access the model of this partialview. IF @Dr. Wily's Apprentice has right how access hidden field available in this partialview

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded to your previous comment, @Kris-I. I've been out of town for a few days. I'll see if I can put together a PoC to verify if my suggestion makes sense. In the meantime, can you provide an example of what kind of data you need to get from the model? That will help us to understand your problem and make sure that our suggestions meet your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the time your javascript code executes, the data it receives is the server response, whatever that may be. If coming from a partial view, then that server response is most likely html, and no, you can't access the model that was used to construct it.

If all you want is access to the model data from your javascript code, then you could try returning a jsonresult from your action method.

If you need the partial view but you also need access to some of the data in the model, then I would embed the necessary data inside of the partial view, possibly using hidden fields. Your javascript code can then retrieve that data from the partial view content.

---

To clarify, you can use jQuery to extract information from a known element in the server's response.  For example, assuming that the `data` parameter in the example is a string of the following HTML:

```
<tr><td><input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="1" />1</td><td><input id="Value" name="Value" type="text" value="Data Entity 1" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Update" /></td></tr>
```

You could extract the value of the "Value" textbox with the following javascript:

```
var value = $(data).find("td input[name='Value']").val();
```

Or you could extract the value of the "ID" hidden field with the following javascript:

```
var id = $(data).find("td input[name='ID']").val();
```

Below is the relevant code of a simple page that I put together to demonstrate this:

### List.cshtml

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.ListOfDataEntities

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<table id="Items">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.DataEntities)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ListItem", item);
}
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$("table#Items tbody tr td input[value='Edit']").live("click", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = row.find("td input[name='ID']").val();
    var jqxhr = $.post('@Url.Action("EditListItem")', { id: id }, function (data) {
        // here, data is a string of HTML, such as <tr><td><input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="1" />1</td><td><input id="Value" name="Value" type="text" value="Data Entity 1" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Update" /></td></tr>
        var value = $(data).find("td input[name='Value']").val();
        alert(value);
        row.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
$("table#Items tbody tr td input[value='Update']").live("click", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var id = row.find("td input[name='ID']").val();
    var value = row.find("td input[name='Value']").val();
    var jqxhr = $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateListItem")', { id: id, value: value }, function (data) {
        row.replaceWith(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

### ListItem.cshtml

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.MyDataEntity
        <tr><td>@Html.HiddenFor((x) => x.ID)@Model.ID</td><td>@Model.Value</td><td><input type="button" value="Edit" /></td></tr>
```

### EditListItem.cshtml

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.MyDataEntity
        <tr><td>@Html.HiddenFor((x) => x.ID)@Model.ID</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor((x) => x.Value)</td><td><input type="button" value="Update" /></td></tr>
```

### HomeController.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AjaxTest.Models;

namespace AjaxTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult List()
        {
            var model = new ListOfDataEntities(new List<MyDataEntity>
            {
                new MyDataEntity { ID = 1, Value = "Data Entity 1" },
                new MyDataEntity { ID = 2, Value = "Data Entity 2" },
                new MyDataEntity { ID = 3, Value = "Data Entity 3" },
                new MyDataEntity { ID = 4, Value = "Data Entity 4" },
                new MyDataEntity { ID = 5, Value = "Data Entity 5" },
            });

            return View(model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult EditListItem(int id)
        {
            // ideally the model would be retrieved from some data source,
            // but this is just a proof of concept
            var model = new MyDataEntity { ID = id, Value = "Data Entity " + id };

            return PartialView(model);
        }

        public PartialViewResult UpdateListItem(MyDataEntity model)
        {
            return PartialView("ListItem", model);
        }
    }
}
```

### MyDataEntity.cs

```
@model AjaxTest.Models.MyDataEntity
        <tr><td>@Html.HiddenFor((x) => x.ID)@Model.ID</td><td>@Html.TextBoxFor((x) => x.Value)</td><td><input type="button" value="Update" /></td></tr>
namespace AjaxTest.Models
{
    public class MyDataEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### ListOfDataEntities.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AjaxTest.Models
{
    public class ListOfDataEntities
    {
        List<MyDataEntity> _DataEntities;

        public ListOfDataEntities(List<MyDataEntity> dataEntities)
        {
            _DataEntities = dataEntities;
        }

        public IEnumerable<MyDataEntity> DataEntities
        {
            get { return _DataEntities; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give sample code to access hidden field in my case ?

Comment: @Kris-I sorry it's taken me so long to get back to you on this. I've added a code example to demonstrate this. Essentially, assuming that your `data` parameter contains HTML, you can wrap it as a jQuery object with `$(data)`, and then you can use the `find` method (or whatever else) to extract whatever you need from that html. Your jQuery code just has to be aware of the structure of `data` so that it knows what to look for.